# Solving this series using special series in algebra(use of mathematics)

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

So I am supposed to find the sum of this series :

**f(n) = 1 + (2*3) + (4*5*6) + .....n terms**

I did this using recursion as follows:

```
def f(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        product = 1
        add = 0
        s = (n * (n+1))/2
        for i in range (0,n):
            product = product * s
            s = s - 1
        add = product + f(n-1)
        return add
```

Now please bear with me

I thought I could do this faster if I could use special series in linear algebra:

Here is what I attempted:

I found the nth term(through some vigorous calculations) : Tn = [image: formula]

Now is there a method I can use this formula to find sum of Tn and hence the series using python.

I also want to know whether we can do such things in python or not?

Comment: Other methods to solve this question will also be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can translate that product to Python using a for loop, analog to how you kept track of the product in your recursive function. So T(n) would be:

```py
def T(n):
    product = 1
    for r in range(1, n+1):
        product *= (n * (n - 1)) / 2 + r
    return product
```

Now as you said, you need to find the sum of T(x) for x from 1 to n. In Python:

```py
def f(n):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        sum += T(i)
    return sum
```

FYI:

`a += x` is the same as `a = a + x`,

analog `a *= x` is equal to `a = a * x`